# Path lengths in the dual slit experiment and the speed of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, interference, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

In the dual slit experiment, we can view the diffraction pattern as the constructive and destructive interference of two waves from the superposition of a single photon. If we analyse the paths through the two slits, we see that two waves emitted at the same time time from the source, only arrive at the screen simultaneously in the center of the screen. For a positions not at the centre, the waves arrive at different times so it is difficult to see how they can interfere. If a particle manifests at a location on the far left of the screen, does the wave coming from the left slit wait for the wave from the right slit so the interference can take effect or is there a probability wave that is instantaneously produced everywhere as soon as the particle is emitted and then this field of probabilities pre-determines the constructive or destructive magnitude at each location on the screen? (this is basically the pilot wave theory).

Now if we take the time from when the particle was emitted (if it can be measured?) to the time the particle arrives at the screen we can in principle determine which path the photon took when the path length through one slit to the screen is different from the other path length. Maybe the measurement of the time the particle was emitted destroys the possibility of observing interference?

In the dual slit experiment the differences in path length are small, but we can make the difference arbitrarily large by considering a similar setup proposed by Wheeler, where the photon is emitted by a source that is millions of light years away.

[image]

[Wheeler delayed-choice experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%27s_delayed-choice_experiment)

If there is a large gravitational lens between the source and the observer, the waves can go either side of the gravitational lens, before coming together and interfering. In this example the the difference in path lengths could be thousands of light years with a corresponding difference in arrival times of thousands of years if we assume the waves travel at the speed of light. If one wave arrives at the observer, does it have to wait for potentially thousands of years, for the other wave to arrive before the interference is determined?

So the question is, can the travel times of the waves be measured in principle and do the probability waves travel at the speed of light or instantly?

P.S. I noticed that similar questions have been asked in this forum, but I don't think anyone has addressed the problem of if the emission time can be measured in principle without destroying the the interference pattern?

Comment: It can not be measured without changing the pattern. A timing measurement means that we move from monochromatic waves to wave packets that have a somewhat defined "time of arrival". If we go overboard with that, then the pattern disappears completely. If we just do it "a little", then the pattern becomes modified. The details are just a Fourier transformation away. A "localized" wave packet is just colored light. None of this has anything to do with quantum mechanics. It's exactly the same with water waves.

Comment: “the waves arrive at different times so it is difficult to see how they can interfere”, what do you think interference is? Anything other than perfect constructive interference *is* the waves arriving at different times. You have this completely backwards. It would be difficult to see how they could interfere if they arrived at the same time

Comment: I'm just having difficulty with the concept of a tsunami wave arriving at my location on the beach constructively or destructively interfering with a wave that takes a longer path around an island and arrives tomorrow.

Comment: I guess the downvotes are due the layman terminology I used, but it a valid question a layman might ask and  I think it deserves an explanation to why the layman assumptions are wrong.

Comment: "  from the superposition of a single photon "   is a  wrong statement.  The single photon is a quantum mechanical entity  and only the ** probability** of measuring its position has a wave dependence. In this answer  I try to clear this up . https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675797/why-does-quantum-physics-use-observation-rather-than-interaction-as-the-term/675820#675820

Comment: If you have two uncorrelated light sources, say two incandescent lamps, due to the fact that they are not coherent, their intensities add because the random phases kills the interference terms. In principle, it does not matter how long the timing difference is, you should be able to see the interference, but in practice, you will find that it is basically impossible to get light sources that have such good temporal coherence to do that experiment. So, instead of seeing one wave arrive first and then interference pattern, you should see one wave first and then brighter wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in general per Feynman, Dirac and many others we know each photon behaves on its own ... the famous statement is  "Each photon then interferes only with itself. Interference between two different photons can never occur..."

One possible explanation for self interference is the virtual EM field, for example an excited electron in an atom in the source is already interacting with the EM field long before the photon is emitted. We do know that excited electrons can remain in an excited state for various periods of time.  There is no reason to not believe that the EM field is active during this phase ... just as a charged particle interacts with every electron in any apparatus.

It is this virtual field that superimposes, interferes, likely works at the speed of light, changes constantly as energy/charges move in the apparatus.

And no, we can never measure times for this virtual field, it is always active, we only perceive the real photons after all the virtual interactions are over.